# mvc3 regularexpression issue

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a regularexpression on my page to allow certain tags of HTML I allow "p"  but if someone  puts  "p style=" it comes out as invalid character how can i change that to allow "p style="

```
[AllowHtml]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([^<]|<em>|</em>|<p>|</p>|<i>|</i>|<b>|</b>|<strong>|</strong>|a z|A Z|1 9|(.\.))*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change this bit

```
<p>
```

to this

```
<p( style=)?>
```

but presumably you want to allow content in your style tag like `<p style="width:20">`

which could be

```
<p( style="[^"]*")
```

and how about single quotes? `<p style='width:20'>`

```
<p( style=["'][^"']*["'])
```

but the *real* answer is not to use regular expressions to parse HTML, it's bound to go wrong. I don't use asp.net but I would imagine there are libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<p>` part to:
`<p( style=('[^']*'))?>`

Please note the `?` which makes the style optional.

To support 'quoted' styles.  You can do something similar with "double-quoted" styles if you wish.